# django relatedname filter not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to do this:

```
search['relatedname__fieldname__gte'] = 3
objs = Model.objects.filter(**search)
```

but it seems not to be working, i am getting only objs with =3 and not >3

am i missing any point here?

Comment: That looks ok, as long as `fieldname` is a numeric field.

Comment: @Alasdair yeah fieldname is IntegerField.

Comment: Can you check the sql dump?: `print objs.query`

Comment: @mariodev thanks very useful tool to check whats goin on in real sql world..